# I want to print the country capitals if the country is chosen

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, input, printing, iteration

Here is the code:

```
import time
from colored import fg
import sys

clr1 = fg("red")
clr2 = fg("blue")
clr3 = fg("yellow")
clr4 = fg("green")

for x in (clr1 + "Hi,\nThis program is made to find out the capital city of countries. For now, there are only around 100 countries which you can find the capitals of.\nThe countries are:\n"):
    sys.stdout.write(x)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.03)

time.sleep(1)

for x in (clr2 + "Afghanistan\nAlbania\nAlgeria\nArgentina\nArmenia\nAustralia\nAustria\nAzerbaijan\nBahrain\nBangladesh\nBelgium\nBenin\nBotswana\nBrazil\nBulgaria\nCanada\nChile\nColombia\nCostaRica\nCroatia\nCuba\nDenmark\nDjibouti\nDominica\nEgypt\nEritrea\nEstonia\nEthiopia\nFiji\nFinland\nFrance\nGabon\nGermnay\nGhana\nGreece\nGrenada\nGuinea\nHaiti\nHungary\nIceland\nIndia\nIndonesia\nIran\Ireland\nItaly\nJamaica\nJapan\nJordan\nKenya\nSouthKorea\nKosovo\nKuwait\nLaos\nLativa\nLebanon\nLiberia\nLibya\nLuxembourg\nMacedonia\nMadagascar\nMalawi\nMalaysia\nMaldives\nMali\nMexico\nMoldova\nMonaco\nMongolia\nMontenegro\nMorocco\nMozambique\nNamibia\nNepal\nNetherlands\nNewZealand\nNiger\nNigeria\nNorway\nOman\nPakistan\nPanama\nPhilippines\nPoland\nPortugal\nQatar\nRomania\nRussia\nSamoa\nSaudi Arabia\nSenegal\nSerbia\nSingapore\nSlovakia\nSomalia\nSouth Africa\nSpain\nSri Lanka\nSudan\nSwitzerland\nSyria\nTaiwan\nThailand\nUganda\nUnited Arab Emirates\nUnited Kingdom\nUnited States of America\nUruguay\nVatican City\nVietnam\nYemen\nZimbabwe\n\n\n"):
    sys.stdout.write(x)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.003)

time.sleep(1)

countries = {
    "Afghanistan": 'Kabul',
    "Albania":'Tirana',
    "Algeria":'Algeirs',
    "Argentina":'Buenos Aires',
    "Armenia":'Yerevan',
    "Australia":'Cnaberra',
    "Austria":'Vienna',
    "Azerbaijan":'Baku',
    "Bahrain":'Manama',
    "Bangladesh":'Dhaka',
    "Belgium":'Brussels',
    "Benin":'Porto_Novo',
    "Botswana":'Gaborone',
    "Brazil":'Brasilia',
    "Bulgaria":'Sofia',
    "Canada":'Ottawa',
    "Chile":'Santiago',
    "Colombia":'Bogota',
    "Costa Rica":'San Jose',
    "Croatia":'Zagreb',
    "Cuba":'Havana',
    "Denmark":'Copenhagen',
    "Djibouti":'Djibouti',
    "Dominica":'Roseau',
    "Egypt":'Cairo',
    "Eritrea":'Asmara',
    "Estonia":'Tallinn',
    "Ethiopia":'Addis Ababa',
    "Fiji":'Suva',
    "Finland":'Helsinki',
    "France":'Paris',
    "Gabon":'Libreville',
    "Germnay":'Berlin',
    "Ghana":'Accra',
    "Greece":'Athens',
    "Grenada":'Saint Georges',
    "Guinea":'Conakry',
    "Haiti":'Port-au-Prince',
    "Hungary":'Budapest',
    "Iceland":'Reykjavik',
    "India":'New Delhi',
    "Indonesia":'Jakarta',
    "Iran":'Tehran',
    "Ireland":'Dublin',
    "Italy":'Rome',
    "Jamaica":'Kingston',
    "Japan":'Tokyo',
    "Jordan":'Amman',
    "Kenya":'Nairobi',
    "South Korea":'Seoul',
    "Kosovo":'Pristina',
    "Kuwait":'Kuwait City',
    "Laos":'Vientiane',
    "Lativa":'Riga',
    "Lebanon":'Beirut',
    "Liberia":'Monrovia',
    "Libya":'Tripoli',
    "Luxembourg":'Luxembourg',
    "Macedonia":'Skopje',
    "Madagascar":'Antananarivo',
    "Malawi":'Lilongwe',
    "Malaysia":'Kuala Lumpur',
    "Maldives":'Male',
    "Mali":'Bamako',
    "Mexico":'Mexico City',
    "Moldova":'Chisnau',
    "Monaco":'Monaco',
    "Mongolia":'Ulaanbaatar',
    "Montenegro":'Podgorica',
    "Morocco":'Rabat',
    "Mozambique":'Maputo',
    "Namibia":'Windhoek',
    "Nepal":'Kathmandu',
    "Netherlands":'Amsterdam',
    "NewZealand":'Wellington',
    "Niger":'Niamey',
    "Nigeria":'Abuja',
    "Norway":'Oslo',
    "Oman":'Muscat',
    "Pakistan":'Islamabad',
    "Panama":'Panama City',
    "Philippines":'Manila',
    "Poland":'Warsaw',
    "Portugal":'Lisbon',
    "Qatar":'Doha',
    "Romania":'Bucharest',
    "Russia":'Moscow',
    "Samoa":'Apia',
    "Saudi Arabia":'Riyadh',
    "Senegal":'Dakar',
    "Serbia":'Belgrade',
    "Singapore":'Singapore',
    "Slovakia":'Bratislava',
    "Somalia":'Mogadishu',
    "South Africa":'Pretoria(administrative); Cape Town(legislative); Bloemfontein(judicary)',
    "Spain":'Madrid',
    "Sri Lanka":'Colombo; Sri Jayewardenepura Kotte(legislative)',
    "Sudan":'Khartoum',
    "Switzerland":'Bern',
    "Syria":'Damascus',
    "Taiwan":'Taipei',
    "Thailand":'Bangkok or Krung Thep Maha Nakhon',
    "Uganda":'Kampala',
    "United Arab Emirates":'Abu Dhabi',
    "United Kingdom":'London',
    "United States of America":'Washington, D.C',
    "Uruguay":'Montevideo',
    "Vatican City":'Vatican City',
    "Vietnam":'Hanoi',
    "Yemen":'Sanaa',
    "Zimbabwe":'Harare'
    
}

time.sleep(1)

user_input = input(clr3 + "What country's capital do you want to find out (That is in the list) ?\n>>> ")
```

So every time the user inputs a country, how do I make it so that it prints out the capital with the fewest possible lines of code. For example i enter France and it gives out Paris. I dont want to use if statements to go through every line and say if user_input == <> : print("Capital"). That way I will have to write the statements over a 100 times. Is there a way to solve this problem

Comment: `print(countries[user_input])` should work, countries is dictionary  and country name are the keys for the dict

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    print(countries[user_input])
except KeyError: # If the user input wasn't found in the dictionary
    print("Invalid Country!")
```